# Images / Photos and text boxes jump to top of page

Tags: microsoft-word, images, photos

Images / Photos, text boxes and text boxes with images embedded in them jump to top of page in some cases and not others.  "Control + arrow keys" have no effect. It is even difficult to drag None of the usual remedies has any effect... "Wrapping Style", "Move object with text", Lock anchor", "Allow overlap", etc. It is even difficult to drag the image to another location on the page and if you do, it can't come withing an inch of the top or it snaps to the top of the page.  This is a frequent problem on multiple computers.

Comment: Have you tried cutting (CTRL+X) and pasting the image. Does that reset it?

Answer (score 0):

If you've exhausted all the usual fixes listed in the question, then another known problem occurs when using the group images function (right click on image > Grouping > Group). If you do this for ANY IMAGE in the document it will cause other images to jump to the top of the page. IT CANNOT BE UNDONE! Even if you ungroup the grouped image, the other images will always jump to the top of the page. Obviously Microsoft embeds some invisible code that causes this.  Try it yourself. Create a multi-page document... insert some images on different pages... group a couple of them... try moving some of the others and you will find that some jump to the top of the page or are otherwise uncontrollable. Note: it doesn't matter if you add new images, delete old images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Click to select the AutoShape.
On the Format menu, click AutoShape.
On the Layout tab, click Advanced.
On the Picture Position tab, change the below box for Absolute position to Page.

I found it on a MS support page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269567